# How to add an image to a theme page template in code?

Tags: theme-development, images

So, I'm trying to do an update to a site's theme layout, and I'm not sure what exactly the right function to achieve what I want is. We have a custom theme that uses a page builder, and we can add custom layouts that are added with Advanced Custom Feeds. For greater control over layout, I'm essentially just hand coding the sections we want to add. From what I've seen in the Codex, the function `get_attached_file` is the closest to what I think I want, but I'm not sure how to get the attachment id from the Media gallery. What I want is some way of pulling any image in the database into a page template and not to manually set the image dimensions and avoiding hard coding image src in the template files. So...what's the better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, but the key is to use `get_posts()` with the proper arguments so as to retrieve the ids of the attachments, e.g.

```
   $args = array(
     'post_type' => 'attachment',
     'numberposts' => -1,
     'post_status' => null,
     'post_parent' => $post->ID
  );

  $attachments = get_posts( $args );
     if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
           echo '<li>';
           the_attachment_link( $attachment->ID, true );
           echo '<p>';
           echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title );
           echo '</p></li>';
          }
     }
```

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attachment_link and https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_attachment_link.

As far as the image dimensions go, you probably want CSS for that, unless you just want to display the image as is.

Comment: How do you get the attachment id?

Comment: The WordPress terminology is a bit confusing. The `get_posts()` function should really be called `get_content_ids()`. There's a single set of ids for all the content -- posts, pages, attachments, etc...

Comment: ... In this case, the ids returned will all be of attachments, because the `'post_type'` argument (which really should be called `'content_type'`) is `'attachment'`.
Anyway, might be preferable to call `get_children()` (which I think is essentially a wrapper around `get_posts()`), then call `wp_get_attachment_image()` to actually generate the `img` tag. The latter will also generate html that references an image of the desired size, if a pre-generated image exists.

Comment: ...let me know if it's still unclear, if you need sample code, or if your attempts don't work as expected or desired.